# MVC date field validation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm expecting the user to enter a date in dd-MMM-yyy format. Thus in order to validate user input I use the following in the model

```
 [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{dd-MMM-yyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
 public DateTime ? SubmittedToDateTime { get; set; }
```

However, I get the validation error : The field SubmittedToDateTime must be a date. when the user input is : 12-Jun-2013.

I also noted that if change the field value from 12-Jun-2013 to 12 Jun-2013 the error won't appear.

Thanks

Comment: What culture is your app running in?

Comment: do you think it is correct format? {dd-MMM-yyy} it should have "yyyy" instead

Comment: Also, I believe you need to reference the token index in the format as well? (e.g. `{0:dd-MM-yyyy}`)

Comment: I have tried yyyy but with the same result. I'm not specifying a culture in the config file. Guess it runs on the default setting of the browser which is en-us

Answer (score 2):

`yyy` won't work. There's `yy` for two-digit display and `yyyy` for four-digit display of years. So you've probably missed one `y`.

Answer (score 0):

As another user mentioned, there's no `yyy` format. either `yy` or `yyyy` for 2 or 4 digit years, respectively.

Also, [`DataFormatString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayformatattribute.dataformatstring.aspx) requires the token index (like a `String.Format`) so instead of just the date output, wrap it in the token syntax:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
```

also, if you *really* want more control (and not opposed to using jQuery-UI) you can create an edit template for `DateTime` and use the [DatePicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) control:

**~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/DateTime.cshtml**

```
@model DateTime?
@Html.TextBox(String.Empty,  String.Format("{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}", Model.HasValue ? Model : DateTime.Today), new { @class = "datepicker"})
```

Then you'd have to reference both jQuery & jQuery-UI in the page and add the following somewhere:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
      dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy' // http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-formatDate
    });
  });
</script>
```

Then, in your view, reference `@Html.EditorFor(x => x.SubmittedToDateTime)`

Comment: I have tried using [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime ? SubmittedToDateTime { get; set; } but with the same result

Comment: Oops, i think that has to do with the format I used. i missed the `MMM` Does `{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}` work?